# Data-column in Rails form builder select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

How do you add a data-column to Rail's form builder select?

Here is the basic HTML that I want to reproduce.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control" data-column="3">
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the code that I can't get right:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :category %><br>
<%= f.select :category, {prompt: "Select Category"}, {class: "input-lg", :id => "category"}, data-column: 3 %>
</div>
```

I have tried putting `data-column` in the `prompt` section and in the `class` section.

Comment: I think you're confusing Ruby and Rails. Ruby doesn't have a "form builder". Ruby, the language, was used to write Rails. So, in your question, you should replace all references to "Ruby" with Rails for it to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
"data-column" => 3
```

---

I thought the problem was only the data-column, this is the complete solution (it's not what you are trying to reproduce but I think this example is more detailed):

```
<%= f.select :category, [], { :include_blank => 'Select Category'}, {:class => 'input-lg', :id => 'category', "data-column" =>  3} %>
```

to get:

```
<select class="input-lg" data-column="3" id="category" name="something[category]">

<option value="">Select Category</option>

</select>
```

If, instead, you are trying just to get the code you specified in your question, you can do:

```
<div class="input-group">

<%= f.select :category, [], {}, {:class => 'form-control', "data-column" => 3} %>

</div>
```

Comment: There wasn't a class given, this gives: <select data-column="3" id="test_category" name="test[category]"><option value="Select Category">prompt</option></select>

Comment: Good answer, but there's a couple things to remember. In questions and answers, pretend you're writing for a encyclopedia, or for Wikipedia, or a text book. Stack Overflow's goal is to be the Wikipedia of solutions to programming problems. Smiley faces aren't a good fit in reference books, right? Also, you don't need to say "Update:", because we can tell by looking the edit history.